# How to Upgrade Elastic Docker from 8.6.2 to 8.7 without loosing anything

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, semantic-search

I installed elastic search and kibana docker from official documentation.

```
docker network create elastic
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2
docker run --name es-node01 --net elastic -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -t docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.2

docker pull docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.2
docker run --name kib-01 --net elastic -p 5601:5601 docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.2
```

Then I created some index and uploaded ml models there. Now I want to upgrade ES to 8.7

How can I do it without losing data/ml models which exist in the older version?

Any idea?

Comment: Here are two ways you may want to try:
1.Upgrade elastic to 8.7 manually in docker, details are https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack/8.7/upgrading-elasticsearch.html
2.export your data to the physical machine,  run a new elastic container of 8.7.
and then import you data to the new container.
docker cp /path/filename containerId:/path/filename
docker cp containerId:/path/filename /path/filename

Before trying, you should backup you container as an image.